# How to parse String to MbMessageAssembly? In Java Compute node IIB

Tags: java, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am quite new to this, and I am struggling with one issue.
In Java Compute Node, through IIB, I am checking if one field has one or more values, and for each additional value I am creating a new duplicate message, except for value, these additional values are overriding.
This is working fine as a expect, see example:

Input :...

```
</leg_flight_no><lineNumber>2</lineNumber><shipper_name>BMW AG</shipper_name> <shipper_reference_hu>1111111;22222222;333333333</shipper_reference_hu></root>
```

Modified message 1:...

```
</leg_flight_no><lineNumber>2</lineNumber><shipper_name>BMW AG</shipper_name> <shipper_reference_hu>1111111</shipper_reference_hu></root>
```

Modified message 2:..

```
</leg_flight_no><lineNumber>2</lineNumber><shipper_name>BMW AG</shipper_name> <shipper_reference_hu>22222222</shipper_reference_hu></root>
```

Modified message3 :...

```
</leg_flight_no><lineNumber>2</lineNumber><shipper_name>BMW AG</shipper_name> <shipper_reference_hu>333333333</shipper_reference_hu></root>
```

But I am struggling to propagate this message out from the Java Compute node. I understand that I cant propagate messages of type `String`, so I am trying to parse this as a `MbMessageAssemble` outAssemble. This is my code:

```
String newMessage = inData.replace(wholeValues, outData); // replace one value with another
                                
MbMessage outMessage = new MbMessage();
MbMessageAssembly outAssembly = new MbMessageAssembly(inAssembly, outMessage);
copyMessageHeaders(inMessage, outMessage);
MbElement outRoot = outMessage.getRootElement();
MbElement outParser = outRoot.createElementAsLastChild(MbBLOB.PARSER_NAME);
MbElement outBodyEl2 = outParser.createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "BLOB", newMessage.getBytes());                                
alt.propagate(outAssembly);
```

But this is propagate an empty message, so the `newMessage` is not parsed to `outAssembly`. Can anybody with this experience help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For future, here is your answer

```
String newMessage = "this is some test";
MbMessage outMessage=new MbMessage();
outMessage.getRootElement().createElementAsLastChild(MbBLOB.PARSER_NAME).createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "BLOB", newMessage.getBytes());
MbMessageAssembly outAssembly = new MbMessageAssembly(inAssembly, outMessage);
out.propagate(outAssembly);
```